# VB 2019 sending data to MS Word with bookmarks

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, visual-studio-2019, bookmarks

I created a program that allows a use to input data into textboxes and then clicks a button to send that data to a word document template. I'm using bookmarks to specify where the data show appear. Everything works except one thing. After the initial document is opened and text has populated the first set of bookmarks, when I go back to the program and change some text and click the button again, it opens a new document and says the file is in use, which it is. I'm wanting to continue to add to the opened document. I have 42 bookmarks, but I can only get the first 4 to populate. Any ideas on how to keep adding text to the same document until all 42 bookmarks have data? [Cable labeler pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d800.png)

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Public Class MainForm
Private Sub CreateLabelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CreateLabelButton.Click
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    'Start Word and open the document template.
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\r101931\Documents\Cable Label Automator\Cable Label Automator\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\CableLabelFormx.docx")

    'Start Adding text from the form to the document template
    If oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark1").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark2").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark4").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark4").Empty = True Then
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark1").Range.Text = AggPPLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark2").Range.Text = AggSwitchNameLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark3").Range.Text = ServerPPLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark4").Range.Text = ServerServerRackLabel.Text

    ElseIf oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark5").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark6").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark7").Empty = True And oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark8").Empty = True Then
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark5").Range.Text = AggPPLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark6").Range.Text = AggSwitchNameLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark7").Range.Text = ServerPPLabel.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMark8").Range.Text = ServerServerRackLabel.Text
End If

End Sub

'All 6 textboxes use the same code to update the labels

Private Sub DeviceNameTextbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeviceNameTextbox.Click
    'Populate labels if textbox is clicked
    AggPPLabel.Text = AggRackPPPortTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & SwitchTypeTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & SwitchNamePortTextbox.Text
    AggSwitchNameLabel.Text = SwitchTypeTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & SwitchNamePortTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & AggRackPPPortTextbox.Text
    ServerPPLabel.Text = RackPPPortTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & DeviceNameTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & DeviceNamePortTextbox.Text
    ServerServerRackLabel.Text = DeviceNameTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & DeviceNamePortTextbox.Text & Environment.NewLine & RackPPPortTextbox.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code and how and when you're instantiating the Word objects.

Comment: Either close your document always after adding text, either keep it open infinitely (needs some form-level variables and logic to check openness).

Comment: Before instantiating the new Word session and opening the document, you should be testing whether Word is running and whether your document is open.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but can you clarify what you mean or give an example?

Comment: For example https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1030887-copying-from-word-doc.html#post3801032 (VBA): You should also change 'oWord.Documents.Open' to 'oWord.Documents.Add', thus creating a new document for each iteration. This will leave all your new documents open, but that's only because you don't have any code to close them.

Comment: You should use 'oDoc.Close()  oWord.Quit()' to close the document.